# how do i join two tables using dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

i have two tables in power bi that i am trying to join or lookup.
the period table has the days, months, and month id.
the data table has the days and data.
i need to pull the month id from the period table into the data table so that i have a table like the final result picture where the month id is now included.

[image: period table]
[image: data table]

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFxAw.png)

i tried using lookup and crossjoin but they dont work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Month = EVALUATE
ADDCOLUMNS (
    Sales,
    "month", RELATED ( 'period'[day] )
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.